# data not showing up in firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im attempting to add user data via a create account view controller which contains all UITextFields (password, confirm password, first name, last name, phone number). when the create account button is tapped, the users email shows up in the authentication section on the firebase website but the user information from the first name, last name and phone number text fields are not passed into the database. I'm new to iOS development and have never used firebase so im unsure what the issue is. the app runs without crashing.

below is my Create Account view controller

thanks in advance

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import QuartzCore
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase

class CreateAccount: UIViewController {

    var refUsers: DatabaseReference!

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var confirmPasswordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneNumberTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var alreadyHaveAccountLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

         performSegue(withIdentifier: "showLoginScreen", sender: self)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.refUsers = Database.database().reference().child("Users");
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {

            print("success")

            self.presentMainScreen()
        }
    }


    @IBAction func createAccountTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text {

            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion:{ user, error in
                if let firebaseError = error {
                    print(firebaseError.localizedDescription)
                    return
                } else {


                    self.addUser()

                    print("this is the first name:", self.firstNameTextField.text!)
                    print("this is the last name:", self.lastNameTextField.text!)
                    print("this is the phone number" , self.phoneNumberTextField.text!)
                    print("success")
                    self.presentMainScreen()
            }




            })

        }
    }

    func addUser(){
        let key = refUsers.childByAutoId().key
        let user = ["id":key,
                    "FirstName":firstNameTextField.text! as String,
                    "LastName":lastNameTextField.text! as String,
                    "PhoneNumber":phoneNumberTextField.text! as String
                    ]

        refUsers.child(key).setValue(user)
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */


    func presentMainScreen(){
        let mainstoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let mainTabController = mainstoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabController") as! MainTabController
        mainTabController.selectedViewController = mainTabController.viewControllers?[0]
        self.present(mainTabController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        //let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)
        //let loggedInVC:LoggedInVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoggedInVC") as! LoggedInVC
        //self.present(loggedInVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Instead of set value use update value

```
let childUpdates = ["/user/\(key)": user]
refUser.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

Hope this helps :)